# Meta value does not save for scheduled posts

Tags: posts, metabox, post-meta

I created a metabox into my posts, it's a checkbox that I checked.

Here's the code for saving the data :

```
 add_action('save_post','save_metaboxes');
 function save_metaboxes($post_ID){

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    //Don't update on Quick Edit
    if (defined('DOING_AJAX') ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if(isset($_POST[ 'is_viewpay' ])) {
        update_post_meta($post_ID, '_is_viewpay', 'active');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($post_ID, '_is_viewpay', '');
    }

}
```

**The problem is**  :

It's working when I manually set my post from scheduled to published (click on publish button)

But when the post automatically published, my meta value does not save at all.

I don't know why it's not working..

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you mean the `_is_viewpay` is empty or does not appear in DB table at all?

Comment: It's on a scheduled.

Comment: @MaxYudin It's empty

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a custom metabox. The problem was the use of $post_id inside the save-function. Using global $post and then $post->ID solved the problem for me.

```
function save_metabox(){
    global $post;

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
        return $post->ID;
    }

    $myData = $_POST['my data'];
    update_post_meta($post->ID;, $myData);
}
```